# php - Is PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT a connect timeout or a read timeout?

Tags: php, pdo

Usually there is two types of network timeouts. First is when trying to connect to server - connect timeout. And second is when connection to server already established and client (PDO in this case) sending query to server and waiting for response from it - read timeout.

I can't find information about is PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT a connect timeout or a read timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on driver. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php):

> PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT: Specifies the timeout duration in seconds. Not all drivers support this option, and its meaning may differ from driver to driver. For example, sqlite will wait for up to this time value before giving up on obtaining an writable lock, but other drivers may interpret this as a **connect** or a **read timeout** interval.

Comment: Would be nice if someone could describe it's meaning for all drivers. And would be even better if authors of PDO could split it into two parameters `PDO::ATTR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` and `PDO::ATTR_READ_TIMEOUT`.